# Use R functions in CPLEX

Tags: r, function, cplex

Is there any way to use the implemented R functions in CPLEX?
I ask specifically about the functions of the `igraph` package that calculate graph parameters. I researched about this and found no positive or negative answer.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34749293/r-interface-with-cplex.

Comment: @RobertMc the link seems indicated the use of CPLEX in R, and what I actually need is to use the R functions in CPLEX.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I get it. Can't help you there, sorry.